# Search for exact value in object (license check)

Tags: javascript

So I have a file with multiple objects like this:

```
{
   "order":{
      "identifier":"B409908375",
      "timeCreated":"2018-11-17T18:27:14.423335",
      "totalPrice":10.000000000000000000000000000,
      "payer_identity":{
         "identifier":"K396677386",
         "firstName":"Erika",
         "lastName":"Mustermann",
         "email":"testbuyer@mail.com",
         "isEmailVerified":true,
         "countryCode3Letter":"DEU"
      },
      "paymentProviderId":1,
      "runtimeLengthDays":-1,
      "runtimeOptionCustomIdentifier":"7fbdc628-893c-4499-844c-7a8c7ecaf325",
      "productSku":"nd79z8jinqmkmtewfrb5"
   },
   "license":{
      "productSku":"nd79z8jinqmkmtewfrb5",
      "issuedToIdentifier":"K396677386",
      "validFrom":"2018-11-17T18:27:21.21126",
      "validUntil":"9999-01-01T00:00:00",
      "isPermanent":true,
      "keyIdentifier":"6b3d646f-cb20-4fc5-b520-e53227379407",
      "isActive":true
   }
}
```

I am trying to do a license check, so look for the `keyIdentifier` and see if it matches an input through a form. The input returns `{license: "input"}` and the result returns `{order: {…}, license: {…}}`. So yeah I want to check if input value can be found in the result/object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Perhaps edit your question to be more specific? As written, I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. Please include what you've tried, where you're stuck, errors, expect vs actual output, etc.  Also: your JSON snippet doesn't contain any arrays. Maybe you meant something else?

Comment: Tried editing it a bit now @DavidMakogon

Comment: As I understood it, he/she wants to search a given input (object) for a key `keyIdentifier` and return its value, e.g. `6b3d646f-cb20-4fc5-b520-e53227379407`.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah trying to see if the input(object) matches the ```keyIdentifier```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if you aim to write your own function to do this from scratch or you want to use built in functions? If you don't have any preferences, you should be able to achieve this like:

```js
const objects = [{object values>}, ...];

function getKeyIdObject(id) {
     return objects.find(current => current.license.keyIdentifier === id);
}

getKeyIdObject ('<insert id here>');
```

This will return the matching object or `null` if not found. If you want to adjust what you return, you can also add `.map(..)` to adjust this.

Answer (score -1):

> So yeah I want to check if input value can be found in the result/object.

It sounds like you have no idea what is the key name where license number is being stored. But you have a clear name keyIdentifier contained into license breanch, so value can be easily get buy {}.license.keyIdentifier. If you try to do all that on fly you can just put both responses (input / result) into variables and then check if key is correct like this:

```
const keyFromInput = // here is what you get from input 
const result = // here is {order: {…}, license: {…}}

if (keyFromInput === result.license.keyIdentifier) {
  //here is what to do if key is correct
} else {
  //here is what to do if key is wrong
}
```

Hope I got you right and you will find this helpful.

Comment: So I managed to get the values out of the object, so I now get multiple licenses as strings.
So I can't really use ```===``` since it returns multiple strings and not just one.
Actually never mind it works perfectly, ty!